# Не форматированные строки python 3

Tags: python, строки, python-3.x

```
>> "C:\Python33" == r"C:\Python33"
True
```

Собственно вопрос: как получить строку вида

```
"C:\Python33"?
```

Python3

Comment: Не понял вопроса.  
@nemodniy, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @nemodniy А разве Вы её не получили? Два раза...

Comment: Простите. Получается строка вида "C:\\Python33" т.е. с двумя \
а нужно что бы именно с одним \

Comment: @nemodniy В Вашем комментарии я двух `\` не увидел. О чём Вы?

Вот две тройки в `Python33` -- да, видно. А с бэкслешами -- увы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@nemodniy](/users/13977/nemodniy), видимо Вы набираете в консоли нечто вроде:

```
>>> r"c\d"
'c\\d'
```

На самом деле в строке всего один слэш, просто в консоль выводится текст с экранированием спец.символов.
Сделайте:

```
>>> print( r"c\d" )
c\d
```